# Convert to int in mySql

Tags: mysql, casting

I'm trying to convert a number to int without any success @ MySQL:

```
select cast (int, 12.345); 
select cast 12.345 as int; 
select convert (12.345, int);
```

and more variations of the above 2 functions - failing at all.
Thanks in advance!
Best Regards,
Eyal :)

Comment: Why don't you simply try to find the correct syntax? Takes less time than posting a question (esp. for us, readers).

Comment: If you need it to be converted to int(11), the highest possible int, see [How to write 'create table ... as select \[some number/function\] as test' in MySQL 5.5 so that the table gets a column of data type int(11)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73072060/how-to-write-create-table-select-some-number-function-as-test-in-mysql-5/73074191#73074191)

Answer (score 1):

You can transform a float into an integer using `CAST` with the `UNSIGNED` type:

```
SELECT CAST(12.345 AS UNSIGNED);
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fYJNiL8SStMkdsqnmTBiuk/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(replace('12.345', '.','') as integer)
```